# Regex to match all HTML tags and tag content except <p> and </p>

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I am looking for a regex to match all HTML tags, except `<p>` and `</p>` that includes the tag content. I am developing in ColdFusion.

There was an [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869/regex-to-match-all-html-tags-except-p-and-p) about matching tags except `<p>` and `</p>`, but I need to grab everything between the tags as well. For instance, the following should match in their entirety:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

and

```
<em>Some text here</em>
```

but not

```
<p>Some text and tags here</p>
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: How do you want to handle the likes of <p>Some <em>text</em> here</p> and <!-- <div><strong> --><p class="warn"> other text here<!-- </strong></div> --></p> ? Etc.

Answer (score 6):

Parsing HTML using regular expressions is very very hard and painful.

You're better off using some sort of DOM-based parser and finding the elements you need.

Comment: +1. Regex cannot parse HTML, as already mentioned in the 2000 questions already posted asking about parsing HTML with regex.

Comment: It's good.  Eventually every single Google hit for "parse html regex" will point to one of these questions talking about why it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's easier to combine a regex with a little extra checking.

So `\<.*?\>.*?\<\/.*?\>`  should match anything between `<..>...</..>` like tags.  You can then programmatically check that the `<..>` and `</...>` are not `<p>` and `</p>` respectively.  It'd probably be easiest to check this if you group them ala:

```
(\<.*?\>).*?(\<\/.*?\>)
```

then check to make sure `$1` and `$2` (or however you do backreferences in your environment) aren't the paragraph open and close tags.

`.*?` specifies minimal matching; I'm assuming your regex environment supports that.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what you're trying to do, but there's a good change you're better off with using the `XmlParse` function to create an XML DOM, and working on that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?  I only did a few checks on it, but it seems to:

```
Regex expr = new Regex(@"<([A-OQ-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I just copied & pasted the C# code.  To get everything between the tags, you need to use \1, and then you need to turn off case sensitivity, so IgnoreCase, or -i, or whatever tool you're using provides that option.  If your tool doesn't do this, then you will have to do A-Oa-oq-zQ-z etc.  Just the regex:

```
<([A-OQ-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>
```

Note this will note match standalone tags, but should get you started.