# Regex to match all HTML tags except <p> and </p> in C#

Tags: c#, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex to match all HTML tags and tag content except <p> and </p>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667818/regex-to-match-all-html-tags-and-tag-content-except-p-and-p)
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

I have a text editor and it takes all the HTML property like span, div, font color, font name, size. So I want to remove all the HTML tags and only keep the Paragraph Tag  and Break Tag.

Comment: Do you expect the HTML posted to have a similar format all the time, or will it be very variable?

Comment: As always: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/572644

Comment: Surely less poetic, but probably clearer in the explanation: [this other one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6751105/146792).

Answer (score 0):

Negation in regular expression it's a very tricky thing. There is way to negate a group: `(?!somepattern)`, but it isnt't supported by all languages and when supported, you should be careful about it.

My advice would be for you to simply match all tags: `<.*?>` . Then, in the language you're programming(this case is C#) iterate through the results and remove the ones which don't match `<p>` or `</p>`.

Not always regular expressions are the best way to solve problems.