# Stuck with regexp

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm stuck with php preg_match_all function. Maybe someone wil help me with regexp. Let's assume we have some code:

```
[a]a[/a]
[s]a[/s]
[b]1[/b]
[b]2[/b]
...
...
[b]n[/b]
[e]a[/e]
[b]8[/b]
[b]9[/b]
...
...
[b]n[/b]
```

I need to match all that inside `[b]` tags located between `[s]` and `[e]` tags. Any ideas?

Comment: are you saying match a [b] tag's contents between two [s] tags OR two [e] tags or between an [s] tag AND an [e] tag?

Comment: I mean AND. In example given above result should be: 1,2,..,n

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want the result to be, given your input?

Answer (score 2):

if your structure is exactly the same as above I would personally avoid regex (not a good idea with these fort of languages) and just check the second char of each line. Once you see an `s` go into consume mode and for each line until you see an `e` find the first `]` and read in everything between that and the next `[`

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity use two `preg_match` calls.

First to retrieve the list you want to inspect `/\[s](.+?)\[e]/s`.
And then use that result string and match for the contained `/\[b](.+?)\[\/b]/s` things.

Comment: any way to do it in one step?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to pattern match something that has a treelike structure, essentially like HTML or XML. Any time you find yourself saying "find X located inside matching Y tags" you are going to have this problem.

Trying to do this sort of work with with regular expressions is a Bad Idea.

Here's some info copy/pasted from a [different answer of mine for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8186824/567650):

Some references to similar SO posts which will give you an idea of the difficulty you're getting into:

- [Regex to match all HTML tags except <p> and </p>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869/regex-to-match-all-html-tags-except-p-and-p)
- [Regex to replace all \n in a String, but no those inside [code] [/code] tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328387/regex-to-replace-all-n-in-a-string-but-no-those-inside-code-code-tag)
- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) - bobince says it much more thoroughly than I do (:

The "Right Thing" to do is to parse your input, maintaining state as you go. This can be as simple as scanning your text and keeping a stack of current tags.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions alone aren't sufficient to parse XML, and this appears to be a simplified XML language here.