# how to restrict HTML elements while allowing others

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

How to only allow certain html tags in a text box

Example:

```
    <Strong>
    <p>
```

The code below is where I have been trying to implement the solution in a class created.

```
[Required]
(Code)
Public string car { get; set; }
```

How would I go about implementing the solution and is it possible at the point where (code) is written above.

Comment: What about XSS? Isn't this that you want to prevent?

Comment: Are you doing this to restrict a CMS from inserting markup? I don't really know a fix from a back end perspective, but you could target that div with css and use display:none or some other attributes to hide the markup in the tags. e.g ( .divname strong {display:none;} )

Comment: I need to implement an error message, if html tags are inserted which are not allowed.

Comment: Yes prevent XSS (JavaScript, VBScript, ActiveX, HTM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Regular Expression allows only the Html tags specified:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^([^<]|<p>|</p>|<strong>|</strong>|a z|A Z|1 9|(.\.))*$")}
```

This allows for the html `<p> </p> <strong> </strong>` to be entered while not allowing any other tags.

Add other tags if required.

Answer (score 1):

First, you would need to disable the validation for you action with [ValidateInput(false)] attribute  but you will need to use that carefully as it will turn off validation for the whole method. You may also disable validation for a particular attribute like :

```
[Required]
[AllowHtml]
Public string article { get; set; }
```

ASP.NET MVC3 has built-in attribute to disable validation at property level - so putting [AllowHtml] attribute on properties in model or view model will disable request validation. This is not safe and puts your site at risk. Now it's up to you to ensure that proper data format is provided so you may wan't to give a try a with Regular Expressions to filter out all html code except for the tags you need. You may wan't to take a look at this answer [Regex to match all HTML tags except <p> and </p>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869/regex-to-match-all-html-tags-except-p-and-p) to get you going. 
example from msdn on how to use regex validation with data annotations :

```
public class Customer
{
  [Required]
  [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$", 
      ErrorMessage="Numbers and special characters are not allowed in the last name.")]
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute(v=vs.95).aspx

you may also try the safer way - to implement BBCode like feature. So instead of html tags you use pseudo html tags like [b] instead of < b >

this is easy to accomplish with jQuery :

assuming #text is a field populated with bbcode like text (not visible) and text2 is formatted display - visible :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var text = $('#text').html();
    text = text.replace("[b]","<b>");
    text = text.replace("[/b]","</b>");
    $('#text2').html(text);
});
```

it's not the smartest code but it was a quick one to show you a direction you can take.

Comment: Regular expressions to filter out html tags (Unsure how to implement it). Had a look at Regex but can't seem to get an understanding of how to implement it in MVC3.

Answer (score 0):

use AllowHtml attribute and then validate the content using IValidatableObject and Regex,
or write a custom validation attribute to allow only some html tags with Regex, see Phil Haack article http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
[RegularExpression("^[^<>,<|>]+$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid entry.")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

To avoid mvc error.