# How can i extract a string text from a file using loop while all over the file?

Tags: c#

For example i have this:

> "Was? Wo war ich? Ach ja.<pa>">

I need to create a new text file that will contain only:

> Was? Wo war ich? Ach ja.

And i have a big file like 43mb and i need to scan all over the file and get only the places that start with `"` and end with `<pa>"` and to get the string between this tags.

I did this code so far:

```
private void retrivingTestText()
        {
            w = new StreamWriter(retrivedTextFile);
            string startTag = "\"";
            string endTag = "&lt;pa&gt;";
            int startTagWidth = startTag.Length;
            int endTagWidth = endTag.Length;
            string text = "\"Was? Wo war ich? Ach ja.&lt;pa&gt;\">";

            int begin = text.IndexOf(startTag);
            int end = text.IndexOf(endTag, begin + 1);

            string result = text.Substring(begin+1, end-1);
            w.WriteLine(result);
            w.Close();


        }
```

But now i need to make it on a big file 43mb xml file. 
So in the constructor i already did StreamReader r;
And string f;
Then i did :

```
r = new StreamReader(@"D:\New folder (22)\000004aa.xml")
f = r.ReadToEnd();
```

Now i need to use it with the code above to extract all the strings in the big file between the startTag and endTag and not only specific text.

Second thing i need to make another function so after i make changes it will know to add back all the extractes text strings to the right places where it was before between the startTag and the endTag

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to look into regular expressions... they make this sort of thing much easier.

Comment: Is your data valid XML? Can you use an XmlReader to process the file? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9d83k261.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for following approach to extract the data.

```
string word = "\"Was? Wo war ich? Ach ja<pa>\"Jain\"Romil<pa>\"";
string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "<pa>\"" };
string ans=String.Empty;
string[] text = word.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);

foreach (string s in text)
{
    if (s.IndexOf("\"") >= 0)
    {
        ans += s.Substring(s.IndexOf("\"")+1);
    }
}
return ans;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar post on how to remove HTML tags using regular expressions. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-sharp-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags).

And another one that you can tweak, [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869/regex-to-match-all-html-tags-except-p-and-p)