# Strip all HTML tags except links and<p> and </p>

Tags: html, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to strip all HTML with the exception of links and `<p>` and `</p>`.

Now , I can just remove all HTML tags except `links`, but I have no idea how to keep the `links tag` and `p` tags in the same time ?

By the way, somebody can recommend some books about how to learn regular expression ?

Comment: Does anyone want to post that link?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex to match all HTML tags except <p> and </p>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869/regex-to-match-all-html-tags-except-p-and-p)

Comment: Use jTidy or HTML Tidy instead in your favorite language.

Comment: You don't need a book, all you need is http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **must** not parse HTML with regular expressions, (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not) and [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)), reason being that HTML can, and cannot be well formed.

You will need to use a specialized framework to do what you need, if you are using Java, you can try [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/), for C# there is the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and for PHP there is the [Simple DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Standard response: Step away from the regex and back up. You do **NOT** use regexes to manipulate HTML. HTML is not a regular language, and therefore cannot be handled reliably with a regex. See this ultimate answer on why not: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0):

Whats programming language do you code? If you use PHP, it supports a good API: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php